# How to add a web folder via command line (Windows)

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, command-line-interface, ldap, webdav

I am trying to add a web folder via command line in windows. At first I though I should use the "net use" command, but when I tried I kept getting System error 67:

> C:>net use *
>   http://dev.subdomain.domain.tdl/dav/
>   the user name for
>   'dev.subdomain.domain.tdl': correctusername
>   the password for dev.subdomain.domain.tdl:
>
> System error 67 has occurred.
>
> The network name cannot be found.

The url I used works in a browser. It's an Apache dav on basic auth LDAP authentication method being used.

Here's the thing... I CAN create a web folder when I use the "Add a network place" wizard. When I do net use, I don't see it listed in the prompt that follows.

What utility do I need to use to mount a web folder in command line?

Comment: What version of Windows?  This matters since webdav is broken in some versions of Windows.

Comment: It's windows XP professional.  I want to make a web folder in command prompt, instead of through the wizard (which works).

Comment: What service pack?

Comment: SP3, but again... I'm not mounting this as a drive.  I want to create a web folder via command line.  I am able to do this with the "Add a Network Place" wizard.  I am attempting to create a program that creates the web folder via cmd.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://devwfb.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-map-https-only-web-folder-to.html the System error 67 may be due to your WebDAV folder requiring an https connection.  The same page has some solutions you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Does putting the site into the Trusted Sites zone in IE make any difference? Maybe try that and then see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an administrative user to do this.  Running a command like this with a non-administrative user produces the "network name not found" error.  So the error message is a bit misleading I guess. It also probably depends on OS version. It's surely different on a UAC-enabled Windows 7 box and a Windows XP box.

Secondly, "net use *" means you want to assign it a drive letter. The * assigns it some free drive letter.  If you do not want to give it a drive letter, just omit the asterisk.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>net use * \\live.sysinternals.com
Drive Z: is now connected to \\live.sysinternals.com.

The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>net use Z: /d
Z: was deleted successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>net use \\live.sysinternals.com
The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>
```

If I try the above in a non-Administrator command prompt, I get a "network path not found" error.