# Adding a web folder via command line (Windows)

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, command-line-interface, ldap, webdav

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a web folder via command line (Windows)](https://serverfault.com/questions/219048/how-to-add-a-web-folder-via-command-line-windows)

I am trying to add a web folder via command line in windows.  At first I though I should use the "net use" command, but when I tried I kept getting System error 67:

> C:>net use * http://dev.subdomain.domain.tdl/dav/
>   the user name for 'dev.subdomain.domain.tdl': correctusername
>   the password for dev.subdomain.domain.tdl:
>   System error 67 has occurred.
>
> The network name cannot be found.

The url I used works in a browser.  It's an Apache dav on basic auth LDAP authentication method being used.

Here's the thing... I CAN create a web folder when I use the "Add a network place" wizard.  When I do net use, I don't see it listed in the prompt that follows.

**What utility do I need to use to mount a web folder in command line?**

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to add a web folder via command line (Windows)](http://serverfault.com/questions/219048/how-to-add-a-web-folder-via-command-line-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Does putting the site into the Trusted Sites zone in IE make any difference? Maybe try that and then see if it works?